# How to return FileStreamResult outside of the main controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was downloading a pdf file in the main controller with the help of `FileStreamResult` like this and the file got dowmloaded just fine:

```
public FileStreamResult Download(Invoice? invoice)
{
    // Create new document.
    ComponentInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");
    var document = new PdfDocument();
    
    // Add page.
    var page = document.Pages.Add();
    static bool IsNotNull([NotNullWhen(true)] object? invoice) => invoice != null;

    var rectangle = page.Content.Elements.AddPath();
    
    rectangle.AddRectangle(new PdfPoint(25, 650),
        new PdfSize(273, 150));
    var rectangleFormat = rectangle.Format;
    
    rectangleFormat.Stroke.IsApplied = true;
    rectangleFormat.Stroke.Width = 1;
    rectangleFormat.Stroke.Color = PdfColor.FromGray(0.5);

    var rectangle2 = page.Content.Elements.AddPath();

    rectangle2.AddRectangle(new PdfPoint(300, 650),
        new PdfSize(273, 150));
    var rectangleFormat2 = rectangle2.Format;

    rectangleFormat2.Stroke.IsApplied = true;
    rectangleFormat2.Stroke.Width = 1;
    rectangleFormat2.Stroke.Color = PdfColor.FromGray(0.5);


    // Save PDF file.
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    document.Save(stream);
    stream.Position = 0;

    // Download file.
    return File(stream, mimeType, fileName);
}
```

But then I tried to put this download function in a seperate file and inject it with dependency injection:

```
public void Download(Invoice? invoice)
{
    genPdf.GeneratePdf(this, mimeType, fileName, invoice);
}
```

And now in the new file the `Return File()` gives an error : **Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method**

```
public class GeneratePdf : IGeneratePdf
{
    FileStreamResult IGeneratePdf.GeneratePdf(ControllerBase controller,
        string mimeType, string fileName, Invoice? invoice)
    {
        // Create new document.
        ComponentInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");
        var document = new PdfDocument();
        
        // Add page.
        var page = document.Pages.Add();
        static bool IsNotNull([NotNullWhen(true)] object? invoice) => invoice != null;

        var rectangle = page.Content.Elements.AddPath();

        rectangle.AddRectangle(new PdfPoint(25, 650),
            new PdfSize(273, 150));
        var rectangleFormat = rectangle.Format;
    
        rectangleFormat.Stroke.IsApplied = true;
        rectangleFormat.Stroke.Width = 1;
        rectangleFormat.Stroke.Color = PdfColor.FromGray(0.5);
        
        var rectangle2 = page.Content.Elements.AddPath();
    
        rectangle2.AddRectangle(new PdfPoint(300, 650),
            new PdfSize(273, 150));
        var rectangleFormat2 = rectangle2.Format;

        rectangleFormat2.Stroke.IsApplied = true;
        rectangleFormat2.Stroke.Width = 1;
        rectangleFormat2.Stroke.Color = PdfColor.FromGray(0.5);
    
        // Save PDF file.
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        document.Save(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;
    
        // Download file.
        return File(stream, mimeType, fileName);
    }
}
```

I tried to make the new `GeneratePdf` inherit from base Controller class and I tried to call the `File()` method on the `ControllerBase` controller but the file still didn't get downloaded. Any other idea on how to fix that and keep the controller and the `GeneratePdf` functionality seperate?

Comment: isnt [`File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.file?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) is a "helper" method in the controller? you might be mixing this up with `File` class under `System.IO`

Comment: it might be better if your `GeneratePdf` returns a stream (dont forget to set the position back to zero) or byte array which your controller can feed into its `return File(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method

This error appears due to the fact the `File` on your `GeneratePdf` is in fact a [`System.IO.File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-7.0) instead of [`Controller`'s helper method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.file?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-controller-file(system-io-stream-system-string)).
[image: Example Error]

You can rectify your code by returning a `Stream` from the `GeneratePdf` and do a `return File(..)` on your controller instead.

```
public class GeneratePdf : IGeneratePdf
{
    Stream IGeneratePdf.GeneratePdf(Invoice? invoice)
    {
        .... //code omitted to safe space
        
        // Save PDF file.
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        document.Save(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;

        // Download file.
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Then on the controller, do it this way:

```
public FileStreamResult Download(Invoice? invoice)
{
    return File(genPdf.GeneratePdf(invoice), mimeType, fileName);
}
```

Note that we return `FileStreamResult` just like your original code. This way controller is only concerned with how to present the data into end user.

I'm surprised after 15 hours theres no answer/progress on this QA.